# How to replace Windows 7 calculator with the one from older version?

Tags: windows-7, calculator

I was curious if such is possible. I copied Vista calc.exe to Windows 7 and it doesn't start. I tried running it in compatibility mode and still nothing. Windows 7 clearly doesn't like Vista :)

Comment: Google says no, in fact returns nothing for installing Vista's calc in W7...some of vista's exe's work in compatibility mode, some just do not work.

Comment: Any particular reason you need or like Vista's calc?

Comment: @Moab the answer is simple -- it sucks! I'm using it while programming and constantly need to switch between hexadecimal and decimal formats but then I may need to also use fractional calculations but for some reason the calc in Windows 7 needs to be switched from Programmer mode just to do floating point calculations. Hate it!

Comment: I have not tried this one, see if it meets your needs...http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21622

Comment: Hah, thanks. But honestly that's the ugliest calculator ever :) I actually got hold of the calc.exe from Windows XP and it works perfect on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: I will take your word on that, never used it. I have an enlarged version of the XP calc, nice on high res screens.